# Calendar Event API Event Date not follow the device timezone

Tags: android, google-calendar-api

Calendar Event API Event Date does not follow the device timezone.

I manually to set the Device timezone to one locale to another but return Event timezone's shifted value no changed. This will be an issue when doing DateTime conversion. How do I do to solve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can manually set your calendar timezone in the [settings](https://calendar.google.com/calendar/render?pli=1#settings-general_11) of your calendar. You can also indicate the timezone when creating an event using the API.

In [inserting an event](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert) in a specific time using the API, your request should look like this:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events?key={YOUR_API_KEY}
{
"end": {
"dateTime": "2017-03-08T8:00:00",
"timeZone": "Asia/Manila"
},
"start": {
"dateTime": "2017-03-08T6:00:00",
"timeZone": "Asia/Manila"
}
}
```

You need to specify the [`start.dateTime`](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert#start.dateTime) and the [`end.dateTime`](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert#end.dateTime) in your request.

Include also the `timeZone` that you want to use. This API needs an IANA Time Zone Format that you can see in this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

You can also set the `timezone` in settings that you see in this [link](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/settings).